# How to turn JSON string into table?

Tags: android, json

How to turn this JSON:

```
{"GetReportResult":
  [
   {"bulan":"4","total":"2448","type":"CHEESE1K"}, 
   {"bulan":"4","total":"572476","type":"ESL"},
   {"bulan":"4","total":"46008","type":"ESL500ML"},
   {"bulan":"5","total":"5703","type":"CHEESE1K"},
   {"bulan":"5","total":"648663","type":"ESL"},
   {"bulan":"5","total":"51958","type":"WHP"},
   {"bulan":"6","total":"6190","type":"CHEESE1K"},
   {"bulan":"6","total":"443335","type":"ESL"},
   {"bulan":"6","total":"30550","type":"ESL500ML"},
  ]
}
```

Into table like this on Android:

```
---------------------------------------------
|   type   | total1  |   total2   |  total3 |
---------------------------------------------
| CHEESE1K | 6190    |   5703     |  2448   |
| ESL      | 443335  |   648663   |  572476 |
| WHP      | 30550   |   51958    |  46008  |
---------------------------------------------
```

What is the best way to do that? Thank you :)

[here is the code that I've made so far](http://www.pastie.org/4164098)

Comment: Does your code work? If it does you should post on codereview.stackexchange.com, if it doesn't you need to explain what the problem is.

Comment: you need to parse your json using a java library like google-gson. Then you can load your data in a TableLayout in android or you can do that by playing around with lineaLayouts as well. :)

Comment: @assylias it doesn't works :(

Comment: @AqifHamid I've try parse json from many tutorial and it works, but in my case, I confuse to use that

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what error you are getting? Can you put the stacktrace?

Comment: @Chandra when I run the activity, but not showing the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy way could be

- parse JSON string using [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

like this:

```
    String json = "{\"GetReportResult\":" + 
"  [" + 
"   {\"bulan\":\"4\",\"total\":\"2448\",\"type\":\"CHEESE1K\"}, " + 
"   {\"bulan\":\"4\",\"total\":\"572476\",\"type\":\"ESL\"}," + 
"   {\"bulan\":\"4\",\"total\":\"46008\",\"type\":\"ESL500ML\"}," + 
"   {\"bulan\":\"5\",\"total\":\"5703\",\"type\":\"CHEESE1K\"}," + 
"   {\"bulan\":\"5\",\"total\":\"648663\",\"type\":\"ESL\"}," + 
"   {\"bulan\":\"5\",\"total\":\"51958\",\"type\":\"WHP\"}," + 
"   {\"bulan\":\"6\",\"total\":\"6190\",\"type\":\"CHEESE1K\"}," + 
"   {\"bulan\":\"6\",\"total\":\"443335\",\"type\":\"ESL\"}," + 
"   {\"bulan\":\"6\",\"total\":\"30550\",\"type\":\"ESL500ML\"}," + 
"  ]" + 
"}"; 
ReportResults reports = new Gson().fromJson(json, ReportResults.class);
List<ReportResult> results = reports.getGetReportResult();
for(ReportResult result:results)System.out.println(result);
```

The ReportResults class:

```
package com.yourcomp.test;
import java.util.List;

public class ReportResults {

    private List<ReportResult> GetReportResult;

    /**
     * Gets the getReportResult.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the getReportResult.</tt>
     */
    public List<ReportResult> getGetReportResult() {
        return GetReportResult;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the getReportResult.
     *
     * @param getReportResult <tt> the getReportResult to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setGetReportResult(List<ReportResult> getReportResult) {
        GetReportResult = getReportResult;
    }


}
```

The ReportResult class:

```
package com.yourcomp.test;

public class ReportResult {

    private String bulan; 
    private String total;
    private String type;
    /**
     * Gets the bulan.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the bulan.</tt>
     */
    public String getBulan() {
        return bulan;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the bulan.
     *
     * @param bulan <tt> the bulan to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setBulan(String bulan) {
        this.bulan = bulan;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the total.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the total.</tt>
     */
    public String getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the total.
     *
     * @param total <tt> the total to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setTotal(String total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the type.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the type.</tt>
     */
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the type.
     *
     * @param type <tt> the type to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ReportResult [bulan=" + bulan + ", total=" + total + ", type="
                + type + "]";
    }


}
```

Then use the parsed result to show in TableLayout.

Comment: another thing i noted was: you would need 'WHP' instead of 'ESL500ML' rt ?

Comment: i have tried the UI portion also. sometimes it may help you to improve the UI. http://www.pastie.org/4164695

Comment: no, I have not try that before. Ok, I'll try to use it :) thank you very much

Comment: wait, I get this error on my log `Could not find class 'com.google.gson.Gson', referenced from method report.weeklyflash.WeeklyFlashIdActivity.onCreate` why I get that error?

Comment: you have to download the gson binary jar from here http://google-gson.googlecode.com/files/google-gson-2.2.1-release.zip, add it to the libs folder and then add this to the project's build path

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13191/discussion-between-blankon91-and-sunil)

Comment: I've add Gson on my libary and I can compile it, but when I run it, there is error message in my log that says `Could not find class 'com.google.gson.Gson', referenced from method report.weeklyflash.WeeklyFlashIdActivity.onCreate`

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are passing `mylist` to `ListAdapter`, but you are not adding `map` to `mylist` anywhere.