# How to create Json using JsonArray and JsonObject

Tags: android, json

I want to create a Json structure which is actually a JsonArray inside a JsonObject.
The sample structure is:

1.

```
{
“req”: [
{
  “ctrlId”:”txt1”
},
{
  “ctrlId”:”txt2”
}
]
}
```

2.

```
{
“req”: [
{
  “ctrlId”:”txt1”,
  “val” : “val1”
},
{
  “ctrlId”:”txt2”,
  “val” : “val2”
}
]
}
```

But i am not able to get it..Any help is appreciated..

Comment: google it out for parsing json

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray req = new JSONArray();

    JSONObject reqObj = new JSONObject()
    reqObj.put( "ctrlId", "txt1" );
    req.put( reqObj );
    reqObj = new JSONObject();
    reqObj.put( "ctrlId", "txt2" );
    req.put( reqObj );

    obj.put( "req", req );
```

The final object is `obj`

Comment: @jesperB...Thanks buddy. Now i got it how to do it.:-)

Comment: @dave21 If this solved your issue then you should give credit to this person by accepting his answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I have this array

```
{
"result": "success",
"countryCodeList":
[
  {"countryCode":"00","countryName":"World Wide"},
  {"countryCode":"kr","countryName":"Korea"}
] 
}
```

Here below I am fetching country details, so I have used **valArray.getJSONArray(1)**

You can use **valArray.getJSONArray(0)**

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonstring);
JSONArray nameArray = json.names();
JSONArray valArray = json.toJSONArray(nameArray);

JSONArray valArray1 = valArray.getJSONArray(1);

valArray1.toString().replace("[", "");
valArray1.toString().replace("]", "");

int len = valArray1.length();

for (int i = 0; i < valArray1.length(); i++) {

 Country country = new Country();
 JSONObject arr = valArray1.getJSONObject(i);
 country.setCountryCode(arr.getString("countryCode"));                        
 country.setCountryName(arr.getString("countryName"));
 arrCountries.add(country);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for doing this parsing. it will make your life simple.

you can have a look at my answers in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239304/how-to-turn-json-string-into-table/11240277#11240277)